# Can't restore Windows 10 home image into a new HP laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-image, clonezilla, m.2

I am using clonezilla for some months now to restore Windows 10 Home images to our production laptops (HP 15-bs190nd).
Recently we bought some new laptops (HP 250 G8) and I am trying to restore the same image on these new laptops.

The error I get in clonezilla is the following: Target disk nvme0n1 does not exist in the image saved from disk(s) “sda”

[image]

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? From my research both the old and the new laptop models have the same type of storage m.2 SSD. The new laptops have extra space but I don’t think this matters.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: If the internal disk is connected to a different mount point, the image is not going to work. In addition, there is likely different hardware requiring different drivers. Its always best practice to create an image for every model, and not reuse an old image.

Comment: Some [say](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214591&p=12975096#post12975096) that you need to partition the disk first and have a partition with the same name, eg `sda5`. Or rename the img.gz folders/files to the partition name you want to restore to. There exist other backup utilities that don't have these limitations.

Comment: @harrymc So for my example those img.gz files would be: sda1.dd-ptcl-img.gz, sda2.dd-ptcl-img.gz, sda3.dd-ptcl-img.gz, sda4.dd-ptcl-img.gz ?

Comment: This seems to implied by the post. If it works, let me know and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: I tried that, but I got exactly the same error